# Spring Kafka - How to configure a single ListenerContainerFactory with multiple listeners having different configurations

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

While using the default KafkaListenerContainerFactory auto configured by spring boot, is it possible to have multiple @KafkaListeners that are using different deserialisers and message converters? Example say one listener is using JsonDeserializer and the other is using BytesDeserializer and BytesJsonMessageConverter. What would be the configuration for that. Is it possible by defining a custom KafkaListenerContainerFactory? Also am i right to think that there should be only one KafkaListenerContainerFactory in an application since its a factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a different factory for each (and indicate which one to use on the `@KafkaListener`), or override individual properties on the `@KafkaListener`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-properties).

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "one", topics = "one")
public void listen1(String in) {
    System.out.println("1: " + in);
}

@KafkaListener(id = "two", topics = "two",
        properties = "value.deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
public void listen2(byte[] in) {
    System.out.println("2: " + new String(in));
}
```